# Determine the type of $L=\{w:|w|\text{ is even, and it has }\frac{|w|}2\text{ consecutive 0's}\}$

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free

I've been solving a lot of questions lately about determining the type of a given language, by type I mean whether it's regular, CFL, in P, Turing-decidable, Turing-acceptable, or all the languages. and I have this language here:
$$L=\{w:|w|\text{ is even, and it has }\frac{|w|}2\text{ consecutive 0's}\}$$
So my main purpose is not actually to know the type of this language but I've faced a lot of questions that asked in the same manner, meaning it asks if the given language has a substring with some characteristics in the first half of a string $w$ in the language or such a thing as appears above.

So I'm searching for an approach that I can adopt to solve such questions.

Also, I would like an answer for the type of the above language.

I assume the language to be CFL but don't really know how to build finite automaton or CFG to decide it, it's clear that it's in P but I'm willing to know if it's CFL or regular.

Answer (score 1):

The $|w|$ is even requirement can be checked by a finite state automaton, so that is not a real restriction. Comparing two numbers (the total length $|w|$ and the length of a consecutive sequence of $0$'s) is usually impossible for FSA.

Now to determine the type, following this intuition, you will have to show the language is CFL by building a suitable grammar, and showing it is not in REG, probably by applying the pumping lemma for regular languages.

To build a CFG first try to build one for $\{ 1^i 0^j 1^k \mid j=i+k\}$, and then change it in such a way that any number of $1$ can be changed into additional $0$.

Comment: Well, I succeeded to build a grammar for the language you've given but I don't really find it helpful to the language I asked for, it looks similar and I think it has a relation to it but I don't really recognize this relation and therefore I can't build a grammar for it, so if you have one please provide me with it.

Comment: @MohamadS.: In a sentence in that language, how many 0's are there, as a function of the total length of the sentence? Bonus question: is it possible for the total length 9f the sentence to be odd?